# Rails - Outputting a list of items with a comma after each record excluding the last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the following right now in one of my user mailer views:

```
<% @participants.each do |participant| %>
    <%=participant.user.full_name%>
<% end %>
```

I want a comma after every record except for the last, I suppose I could add an if block to see if the current record is the last, but that seems like a lot of code. Does rails have a better way to output a comma after every item excluding the last.

```
Good: XXXXX, XXXXXX, XXXXX
Bad: XXX,XXX,XXXX,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could do something like

```
@participants.map{|p| p.user.full_name}.join(",")
```

You also may want to look into the [`to_sentence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence) method that Rails adds to the Array class; it lets you do stuff like output "xxx, yyy, and zzz" automatically.

Comment: Was just signing in to post the same and you beat me to it. Just remember to add <%= before and %> after.

Answer (score 19):

```
["Apple", "Orange", "Pie"].join(", ") => "Apple, Orange, Pie"
```

in more complex job:

```
<% @participants.each do |participant| %>
  <%= participant.user.full_name %>: <%= participiant.comment %><%= "," unless participiant == @participiants.last %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 8):

If your actual case is more complicated (would benefit from partials), you can vastly simplify it by replacing your loop with a partial collection:

```
<%= render :partial => "name", :collection => @participants, :spacer_template => "comma" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<% @example.each_with_index do|example,index|%>
 <%=example.name%>
 <%= "," unless @example.size==index+1 %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also [do it with css](https://gist.github.com/crwang/715d1192e3c64703e720)

```css
.list-csv {
   display: inline;
   list-style: none;
 }
 .list-csv li {
   display: inline;
 }
 .list-csv li:after {
   content: ", ";
 }
 .list-csv li:last-child:after {
   content: "";
 }
```

```html
<ul class="list-csv">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
 </ul>
```